# Performance on intermediate output compression

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce

I tried to compare mapreduce performance with/without compressed intermediate output of mapper.

```
myJobConf.setCompressMapOutput(true);
```

Experiment :

- 1st : Without compression
- 2nd : With compression

The result is mapper performance in #2nd experiment is faster but reducer performance was getting slower.

Any explanation about this?